# Add a string to file .pot using Poedit

Tags: translation

I want to add a string to a pot document for language, but it says there’s an error.
I have opened file .pot with a text editor and I have add this code

```
#:D:\Programe\InstantWP\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-
content\themes\sydney-child/category-38.php:56
msgid “”
“Read more”
msgstr “”
```

while in my file I have add this one

```
<?php _e( ‘Read more’, ‘sydney-child’ ); ?>
```

Then I have downloaded file .pot and I have opened it with Poedit, I have add the translation “Read more”, but when I update it says: “Source code not available. Translations can’t be uploaded by source code because there is no source code in the path specified in catalog properties” (the message was Italian, so I hope to have well translated in English)

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way I work with Poedit is:

- Open Poedit
- Open the .pot file with Poedit
- Define the language of the translation
- Find the info you want to translate on the left collumn
- Place the translation on the right collumn
- Save the .po
- Compile the .mo
- Save both on the 'language' folder of the theme

Since you are trying to create a term where it doesn't exists, the second line of your first step looks incorrect.

```
#: theme-name.php:123 // the reference
msgid "Page Title" // the original term
msgstr "" // the translation
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/

Comment: Hi Marcelo, my problem is that I want to add the info to translate, because there wasn't in the theme originally. So I have read to open the file .pot and add that code. Isn't it right?

Comment: Ok, my bad, I missunderstood that. In the first part of the code, seems wrong. 

The correct would be: msgid “Read more” .

Try the documentation page [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/) .

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear

Comment: Hi Marcelo, unfortunately it doesn't still work. I have installed another plugin, Loco Translate, and this way I have understood I have badly configured my child theme because it says "Unconfigured bundle. This bundle isn't set up for translation in a way we understand. It needs configuring before you can do any translations.". While modifying file po of parent theme it works. Can you tell me how I have to set up the child theme?

Comment: You can use a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/

Or you can see the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes